# water hammer after a regulator is added to system

Tags: water

my local water dept changed my meter from a star meter to a setup that has an s bar with a regulator.lived here over 30 years and never had a regulator and never checked pressure.have hammer very bad when flushing toilets with regulaor set at 55 psi.remove regulator and add a jumper hammer stops but my psi is 95. what is causing hammer? thanks for any input.

Comment: Something's wrong - can't imagine that a lower pressure causes hammer.  Sounds like the hammer is happening inside the new equipment.  Maybe check with a plumber to see if a ballast tank can be added right there.

Answer (score 1):

You may have [air chambers](http://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/plumbing/how-to-fix-pipes5.htm) that drained during the meter installation and refilled with water, rather than air.

First, check that any existing air chambers are working. You may need to shut the main valve and completely drain the system for a while to get air back into the chambers. Most are inaccessible, inside walls, so are not easily replaced, but you can add another chamber elsewhere.

Also make sure that pipe brackets (hangers) are firmly mounted, since a loose pipe exacerbates the issue.